# what are the differences between addr and mountaddr NFS mount options?

Tags: nfs, mount, ip-address

I realized that the `/proc/mounts` include some parameters which are not shown in the `/etc/mtab` file and by the `mount` command. For instance, `mountaddr`.

In my Linux boxes both values `addr` and `mountaddr` match. Should they match always?

What are the differences?

Is `mountadd` parameter related to `rpc.mountd`?

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

As you already pointed out, for NFS versions 2 and 3 an additional mountd process is required to get an initial file handle. Usually, it run on the same host where nfsd is (that's why it matches on your host). However, some exotic setups (RDMA+TCP) may require to move mountd process to a different host, protocol and so on. IOW, mountadd is a pointer to mountd process and addr is a pointer to nfsd.